# Typo3 database query - access elements in collection

Tags: php, typo3

I am creating a query for one of my repositories and want to order the results by a field that contains a collection of elements.

I know, that i can access attributes of single objects by using the point-notation. But is there also a way to access, for example, the first entry of the collection?

```
...
$query = $this->createQuery();
if ($orderBy == 'collection') {
  if ($ordering == 'ascending') {
    $query->setOrderings(
      array(
        // Get only the first entry of the collection
        "collection.first.attribute" => \TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
      )
    );
  } else {
    $query->setOrderings(
      array(
        // Get only the first entry of the collection
        "collection.first.attribute" => \TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
      )
    );
  }
}
...
```

The definition of the collection in the model

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection<\Central\Domain\Model\Location>
 * @ORM\ManyToMany()
 */
protected $collection;
```

Location is thereby another Model which has a field "attribute" that i want to access.

Now I try to access the first - or ideally a specific - element from the collection. Is that possible directly within the query?

Comment: It's probably me, but I don't manage to understand your "collection" field, and if your Model is built according to extbase principles. Btw. you have set the tag "fluid", but you're referring to extbase only ATM, as there is no templating involved.

Comment: I added the definition of the collection field from the model and removed the falsly added fluid tag. My fault - sorry for that.

Comment: I think I won't be of much help here, but can't you access `Location` with a separate query and then $query->getFirst() beforehand?

Comment: Are you sure this is Extbase code and not TYPO3 Flow? There is no Doctrine in Extbase, the "equivalent" of a collection in Extbase would be an ObjectStorage.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz, sorry for the confusion